# VB MySQL syntax error near line 1

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I receive a message saying incorrect syntax near line 1. Below is the code that I am using:

```
Mysqlconn.Open()
Dim Mysqlconn As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Dim ImportDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Main([Character],[Import_Date]) VALUES(@character, @import_date)")
COMMAND.Connection = Mysqlconn
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@character", Character.Text)
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@import_date", ImportDate)
COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show("Ore counts for " & Character.Text & " imported successfully")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is from the `[]` around your fields. Remove them. If you want to escape a field, use tick instead.

```
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Main
                            (`Character`,`Import_Date`) 
                            VALUES (@character, @import_date)")
```

Comment: I tried with and without the tick and I am still receiving the same error message. Would me posting the full error message help?

Comment: @user3741290, yes please post the full error message

Comment: You have an error in you SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Character,Import_Date) VALUES('test','2014-06-14')' at line 1

Comment: @user3741290, it says `Character` need to be escaped because it's a reserved keyword. Try to escape it with the back tick ` like in the answer.